# how to use Big Query Migration Services with GCO

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, database-migration

I want to use Big Query Migration Services (BQMS) with GCP.
can anyone help me to setup on local or use with GCP itself.
#GCP

1. Object conversation in batch.
2. local setup if possible.
3. Possible set of conversation from teraadata to BQ / MSSQL to BQ